# web page scaling

Tags: html

I'm learning web development and so far have created [this](http://mygolfscore-app.com/) app to track my golf data

Now as you can see via mobile or PC everything very small. This is mostly an app for phones since you'd use this on the golf course itself so I would like to be able to scale this by %'s where say the buttons on the first page take up `20%` of the height (the rest being spaces) and they are evenly distributed height wise. They would also maybe take up `75%` of the width of the browser and centered.

Back in the day I would use `HTML` tables but I'm hearing that's considered a no no these days. So what's the idea on how I would achieve this sort of scaling/positioning. Any examples or pointers?

Comment: use a custom grid, http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap for exemple

Comment: are we able to place elements based on percentages? would that maybe require javascript to dynamically do that?